# QGIS - filter by polygon size

Tags: qgis

I'm very new to this so bear with me.

Hopefully a relatively simple query.

I have a city map with property boundaries and I am wanting to filter the boundaries by lot size. i.e just show lots (or polygons) of a certain size, or between two sizes. i.e. lots over 700m2, or lots between 800 and 900m2.

The information I have pulled in doesn't have an area column associated with it so thinking I will need to add my own expression?

Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just dig into the field calculator, the hints on each function are rather helpful. What you're looking for is `$area`, which gives you the area of a polygon in square meters - provided your CRS is a projected one (e.g. UTM).

Either you run the field calculator and then categorise your layer by the column containing the polygon size, or you directly tell the symbology to categorise based on `$area` (see screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Erik! I've had a play around there and managed to get it to filter as I was after.

My next question then:

I am looking to filter data by information from two separate layers. i.e. by area from my boundaries layer, then by suburb location from my street address layer.

Can this be done without combining them into one set of data?

Comment: It would be better if you asked this in a separate question, though I think there have been similar questions already.

Comment: Ok will have a look around and repost if can't work it out. Thanks.